# How to store Carbon DateTime ISO object in Sub Json Document in Laravel 5.2 MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime, laravel-5

I am trying to store Carbon datetime in Sub Json Document but instead of storing in ISO format its storing in different way shown below.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5791bc3d6e79d211aa5be019"),
"breakUps" : [ 
   {
        "amount" : 2000,
        "expiry" : {
            "date" : "2016-09-05 06:25:01.000000",
            "timezone_type" : 3,
            "timezone" : "UTC"
        }
    }
],
"updated_at" : ISODate("2016-07-22T06:25:01.576Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2016-07-22T06:25:01.576Z")
```

Instead it should have been stored like **ISODate("2016-07-22T06:25:01.576Z")** format.

My Eloquent Model class is:

```
class Configurations extends Eloquent
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    public  $timestamps = true;
    protected $collection = 'configurations';
    protected $dates = array('created_at','updated_at','breakUps.expiry');
}
```

PHP Code which i am using for Saving the Object

```
$config1 = new Configurations();
$config1->breakUps = [['amount' => 1000, 'expiry' => Carbon::now()->addDays(30)]];
$config1->save();
```

Comment: Can I see how you are saving the breakUps

Comment: topic being discussed here https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date mutators in Laravel do not support dot notation and hence,

```
protected $dates = ['breakUps.expiry'];
```

just won't work. One simple way to solve this problem is to move the key to the root of the document as `breakUps_expiry`.

```
protected $dates = ['breakUps_expiry'];
```

There is already a issue logged on laravel-mongodb github page, you can [track it here](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB/issues/109).

Answer (score 0):

The work around which worked for me was to use raw Mongo Date object **new \MongoDate()**, and while returning it, use Carbon methods